# What are the incentives behind mining different coins (i.e., profit-switching)?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, mining-profitability, mining-hardware, mining-reward

Consider for example BTC and BCH (and possibly BSV) that are coins with significant market capitalization and share the same algorithm (SHA-256). We observe:

(i) Large miners (or mining pools) divide their hash rate between BTC and BCH (and possibly BSV).

(ii) Typically the mining profitability of BTC and BCH (and possibly BSV) is not exactly the same.

(iii) There are other SHA-256 coins with smaller market capitalization, but significantly higher mining profitability.

How do profit-seeking miners determine which coins to mine? How do they decide what fraction of their hash rate to allocate to each coin? How do they determine when a coin is "too small to mine"? Does too frequent switching "waste time", or is switching near instantaneous?

What are the main risk factors they take into account? Is the main concern price volatility and the fact mining reward cannot immediately be converted to USD?

P.S. I understand some hash rate is not allocated optimally, for example because of miners not paying attention or wanting to support a given network for personal reasons. I am focusing on somewhat professional mining operations where maximizing revenue is a priority.

Comment: the obvious incentive would be more profit?

Comment: Yes, but looking at the data shows cases where Crypto A may yield a higher mining profit than Crypto B for an extended period of time, which means that miners do not jump on what seems like arbitrage opportunity, so there must be other factors at play.